# pandas insert many new columns from existing columns raises "highly fragmented warning"

Tags: python, pandas

My code is like this:

```py
df.columns = ['cpu_0', 'cpu_1', 'cpu_2', 'cpu_3'..., 'cpu_47']
for i in range(48):
    df['new_cpu_{}'.format(i)] = df['cpu_{}'.format(i)] * 100
```

There are about 180k rows in the dataframe, my code raised warning below:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop here.

Use vectorial code:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.mul(100).add_prefix('new_')], axis=1)
```